# HTML form with checkboxes and editable input boxes

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit

Let me try and describe what I am trying to accomplish:

I want to display a form using a table where each row has a checkbox, a unique identifier for the item in that row and a suggested quantity. The quantity is editable and the user can select a subset of the rows.

The form would submit the following:
For each selected row, the unique identifier and the quantity will be submitted to the server.

I can picture somehow using javascript to "activate" which rows get submitted, but I can't wrap my head around a solution for pairing up the UID + Qty pair.

Any suggestions are welcomed!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a form like this:

```
<?php
$width = 10; 
$height = 5;
echo '<form ...>';
echo '<table>';
for($i=0;$i<$height;$i++){
    echo "<tr>";
    for($j=0;$j<$width;$j++){
    echo <td>';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$i.'x'.$j.'" />';
    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$i.'x'.$j.'value" value="la valeur" />';
    echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
echo '<submit...>';
echo '</form>';
```

And then in the treatments part, you can make the two loop, verifying if the checkbox is checked and update the value if it is

Answer (score 0):

If your server side language supports it, I would recommend using array syntax. e.g.

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <input type="checkbox" />
 </td>
 <td>
  <span>NAME</span>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" name="qty[5]" value="10" />
 </td>
</tr>
```

The server side language would then just need to run through the POSTed `qty` array, where the index is the UID, and the value is the Quantity. This model can be expanded like so:

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <input type="checkbox" />
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" name="name[5]" value="Name" />
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" name="qty[5]" value="10" />
 </td>
</tr>
```